# Как сделать "резиновый" HEADER ?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать резиновые элементы, приложил рисунок.

[image]

Вот еще мой вариант, но почему-то не растягивает боковые элементы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Документ без названия</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #93A5C4;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar2 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #93A5C4;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar1">
        <p>Левый</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Центральный</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar2">
        <p>Правый</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: так вроде бы все прорезинено 
[пруф][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/qWGQb/1/

Comment: @sonniy центральный блок, а мне нужны боковые, а центральный фикс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать [display: table-row](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) для контейнера и table-cell для контента и сайдбаров.

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-row;
}

.content, .sidebar { 
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: table-cell;
}

.sidebar { background-color: #93A5C4; }

.content { 
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.left { width: 30%; }
.right { width: 25%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar left">
        <p>Левый</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Центральный</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar right">
        <p>Правый</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/yz6y5/)

Comment: Вообще отлично :) Спасибо!